# Occasional video adverts breaking custom WP theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I built up this Wordpress theme for my buddy. The design was already set, so I just built what I think/thought is a pretty robust template.

We've had a few issues a long the way, and the final stumbling block is the ad block on the top of the sidebar on the right hand side.

If you refresh until it displays a video, it breaks everything - not only the stuff that's below the sidebar call, but the body too.

Can anyone please give me some insight? I'm going insane. I've been working on this project for too long and just want to fix this final problem.

http://www.touchlinetalk.com/

Uh, help!?

Comment: this might be better answered on the WordPress SE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid (check with http://validator.w3.org/). A lot of elements are not closed, overlapping, some anchors are not closed, etc. Adding your video probably introduces a new div element or something like this, which actually interfers with the overlapping other elements you have in your page and breaks the layout. You should give a link to the page that does not work (call it "proof of concept") and not to a page that is OK. 
If you are using WordPress, here is a really handy function for you, to avoid non-closed tags: `force_balance_tags()`. It closes tags that havent been closed. More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags

Comment: Ah, thanks for your feedback. I see that tag being very handy...

Not completely sure how to implement it with this ad code though (which is opening a list but not closing it), but I'm sure I can figure it out.

Comment: Post your code if you want more help. This is not a tag, but a function. It has to be used in PHP parts of the page. More info here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags. But more than this, you should validate your code, because that's where your problem came from.